# How to manage large data in a Mean Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, pagination, mean-stack

i am pretty new to Angular/Mean application development.

I am building a MEAN Stack Application for NGO process Management.
In this app, a new NGO is registered. This NGO can have sub-units based on different locations.  New Members are added to the sub-units.

All the other required functionalities are working fine.
Currently, we are having around 4 NGO`s with 22 sub-units and around 150 members attached to the sub-units.

Now for managing large datasets **(which will happen in this app once more NGO`s and members gets added)** i came around 2 ways to achieve this.
**1) Pagination in Mongodb
  2) Server side pagination in Angular**

However, i am still not sure about which method should be adopted in this scenario or we require to have a mix of both.

Currently, i am using Angular service to fetch all user data at Component Init and storing it in a local variable. But once the user data becomes too large this approach will fail as service may get overloaded with data.

Versions i am using for development is as follows:-

**NODE:    v6.11.0
  ANGULAR: 4.0.0
  MONGODB: 3.4.4**

Any suggestions to use cases or links to implementation scenarios will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to do pagination at server side when your dataset is large. In order to implement pagination at server side I would suggest you to go through the example in link below...

[https://github.com/rorgonas/mongocart][1]

Hope it helps!!